# Events and DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Let's assume that I have a page with a two column layout where the left column is a set of links and it loads the associated html page/template in the right column when that link is clicked.

Upon loading a template, there's a template handler that gets initialized as a singleton via requirejs and it defines some methods and handlers like:

```
SomePage.prototype.saveHandler: function(e) { ... }; // Page handler has a handler

SomePage.prototype.initialize: function() {
    $('#btnSave').on('click', saveHandler);
}
```

Then, I'm attaching DOM events through an initialize method every time the page loads.

```
SomePage.initialize(); // This attaches the click event
```

Now, when I click another link on the left, a different template page is loaded and the above process repeats for that page.

I'm wondering what happens to the click event that was attached earlier to the btnSave element? Is it now a dangling event handler in the jQuery cache?

If I try to remove it when the same page loads again, will it actually remove the original event?

```
$('#btnSave').off('click', saveHandler);
```

Does executing the following block prevent memory leaks / dangling references?

```
// The potential problem here is that btnSave is part of the newly loaded template 
// and not the element i attached the handler to earlier (which doesn't exist anymore)
$('#btnSave').off('click', saveHandler);

$('#btnSave').on('click', saveHandler);
```

What is the best way to ensure I don't end up with dangling references and memory leaks. This is a potential question for plain JavaScript too. My understanding is that the above will not work when the template page is refreshed. I am going experiment with it in the meanwhile, but it would be nice to know how the experts handle this.

Comment: I definitely use `off` and then `on` right afterwards, as you did. But is there any possible way for you to call the `off` *before* you reload the template?

Comment: I've thought of that pattern as a solution, but I'm not sure if I need that yet because jQuery might be handling it internally. If each page implemented an interface and upon loading registered itself as the current page, then a global link handler could do something like app.cache.currentPage.cleanup() which could have all the offs in it.

Comment: I think you are correct in that it creates a ghost element by not doing it...

Comment: I think when the element is disposed the attached events also get disposed. So if clicking on any link replaces the HTML elements on which click event is bound there is no need of "Off"

Comment: Why don't you use ng-click instead attaching "on click" event? If you need to bind to DOM elements use directives. That looks like JQuery not like angular.

Comment: jQuery could potentially use a WeakMap to implement things like this, so they'll be GCed if the element goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this slide from Andy Osmani a javascript guru. You will find the answer about memory leak and circular references here:
https://speakerdeck.com/addyosmani/javascript-memory-management-masterclass

Comment: Thanks for posting. This is great! I'm familiar with the memory tools in the chrome debugger. One of these day's I'll try to find some time to profile it through the memory profiler and uncover the mystery. Another thing I'll end up doing is looking into the jQuery source. I think an easy fix for this would be to introduce functionality that allows a unique identifier to be passed along when registering the event and internally jQuery could replace the existing handler with the new.

Answer (score 0):

When you load The new tmpl you need attach event only for this. For example:

$("#btnSave", $(newly_tmpl)).on("click",.....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching click event to button, you should attach on click function to the button run time  after template load. like this

```
var element = $("<div id='tempDiv' class='main_container o-hidden'><button value='Click' id='btnSave'/></div>");

$("#btnSave",element).each(function(){
    $(this).attr("onclick","tryMe();");
});
```

It will attach tryMe click function to your button, element variable should be created from your template content.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply make it more of a delegated event and only register it one time:

```
$( ".someParentThatsAlwaysOnPage #btnSave" ).on( "click", function() {
  var somePage = getMeContextOfProperObject();
  somePage.saveHandler();
});
```

That way the click event is only bound once and jQuery will update the listener scope as the DOM changes. All you would need to do is provide a means to get the proper object. Without seeing more of your code I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks! Save is just an example. Most pages will have different event listeners based on their content. Your suggestion is good, but it works only if there were an interface each page could implement. However, that's not feasible in this case because pages don't have a common denominator past save/cancel type of functionality.